# One line C program with include?

Tags: c, gcc, include

Right now I have this

```c
#include <zlib.h>
int main ()
{
    puts (ZLIB_VERSION);
}
```

As an exercise, is there any way I could get it to compile on one line, something like

```c
#include <zlib.h>; int main (){ puts (ZLIB_VERSION); }
```

I can get it to compile on two lines, but the include is preventing one line.

Comment: `#include` is a preprocessor directive and will continue until the line is terminated or the directive is ended.

Comment: @StevenPenny - if it's for that case, you'll still have to emit a newline after the include. Sorry~

Comment: @StevenPenny: Then see my answer which might be helpful for the related problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do exactly what you want. With that said, if this is part of a build system, it would be **a lot** better to use the `-E` option to the compiler to preprocess a file containing simply

```
#include <zlib.h>
ZLIB_VERSION
```

and then parse the output. This way you avoid running a program generated by the compiler, so your build doesn't break when cross-compiling.

Answer (score 1):

No, the include directive goes on its own line.

The relevant portion of the standard is `C11 6.10.2 Source file inclusion` where it defines the `#include` directive as one of:

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
# include "q-char-sequence" new-line
```

Note that the newline is an *integral* part of the directive.

I'm not *entirely* certain why you need it on one line anyway. Most programs which can output text can quite easily inject newlines into the stream anyway, such as with:

```
pax> printf '#include<stdio.h>\nint main(void){return puts("Hi"),0;}' \
...> | gcc -o testprog -xc -

pax> ./testprog
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many files you are limited to. If it isn't one, then you can add another file that contains all the code and `#include` that one. E.g.:

### some_header.h:

```
include <zlib.h> 
int main () 
{
    puts (ZLIB_VERSION); 
}
```

### main.c:

```
include "some_header.h"
```

But I don't think that's what you really want. Like everyone else said, the preprocessor deals with lines and there is no delimiter in C to start a new line for the preprocessor. (There is the `\` delimiter that makes the preprocessor treat the next line as a continuation of the current one, but not the inverse.)

Answer (score -1):

Being a bit naive, standard C requires an empty newline at the end of your source code, so 1-line programs that actually do something are impossible.

Update: this is no longer required in C++11